# image highlighting on click

Tags: javascript, html, image, jpeg

I have .jpg images for buttons to cycle through a gallery.  When I click these buttons fast twice, it seems to highlight the image... is there a way I can "turn off" this highlighting?  I didn't really know how to google this so I am asking here.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about a focus rectangle? a picture or some code would help.

Comment: @Dutchie432 not a focus rectangle, but the blue highlight you get when you double-click text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this other thread talks about what you need:
[How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)